# Chrome - keep column width minimum

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

I have a table that has "limited width" and "wide" columns. The expected behavior is when table is resized, the limited width columns become the smallest possible, while wide column fits the usable space.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
.limited {width:0;overflow:hidden;}
.wide {overflow:hidden;}
.limited div, .wide div {max-width:10em;white-space:nowrap;}
table {width:100%;}
</style>
<table id="example" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="limited"><div>veeeeeeee eeeeeeee eeeeee eeeeeeeeery</div></td>
            <td class="wide"><div>looooooooo ooooooooooo oooooooooooooooooo ooooooooooooooooo ooooooong</div></td>
            <td class="limited"><div>text</div></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The copied code behaves as expected in Firefox and in IE9, but doesn't in Chrome. How can I have the expected behavior in Google chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.limited { width:1%; overflow:hidden; }

Answer (score 0):

```
.limited {width:1px;overflow:hidden;}
```